# How to create a series of list elements using for loop?

Tags: r, list, loops

I have some large dataframes containing multiple timeseries where I'm trying to create a list of the individual timeseries. The data isn't well structured with identifiers so going down the split route doesn't seem right why I'm trying the subsetting route.

The problem can be demonstrated like this:

```r
set.seed(1)
test1 <- matrix(rnorm(90), nrow = 10, ncol = 9)
testobj <- list()
indexlist <- list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9)

for(i in indexlist) {
    for(j in (1:3)) {
        testobj[[j]] <- test1[, i]
    }
}
```

The result is my list `testobj` being a list of 3 elements containing the last subset element of `test1[, 7:9]` rather than

```r
testobj[[1]] <- test1[, 1:3]
testobj[[2]] <- test1[, 4:6]
testobj[[3]] <- test1[, 7:9]
```

which I'm really after. When I run `for(i in indexlist) {print(i)}` in the console it seems to generate the right 3 subsetting index, so if anyone can help explaining why its going wrong and suggest a correction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `for` loop you would need only one loop to loop over `indexlist`

```
for( i in seq_along(indexlist)) { 
     testobj[[i]] <- test1[,indexlist[[i]]] 
}

#[[1]]
#            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
# [1,] -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737
# [2,]  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630
# [3,] -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498
# [4,]  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170
# [5,]  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575
# [6,] -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874
# [7,]  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551
# [8,]  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238
# [9,]  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006
#[10,] -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156

#[[2]]
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.35867955 -0.1645236  0.3981059
#...
```

However, you can also use `lapply`

```
lapply(indexlist, function(x) test1[, x])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE`

```
sapply(indexlist, function(x) test1[, x] , simplify = FALSE)
#[[1]]
#            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
# [1,] -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737
# [2,]  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630
# [3,] -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498
# [4,]  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170
# [5,]  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575
# [6,] -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874
# [7,]  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551
# [8,]  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238
# [9,]  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006
#[10,] -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156

#[[2]]
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.35867955 -0.1645236  0.3981059
# [2,] -0.10278773 -0.2533617 -0.6120264
# [3,]  0.38767161  0.6969634  0.3411197
# [4,] -0.05380504  0.5566632 -1.1293631
# [5,] -1.37705956 -0.6887557  1.4330237
# [6,] -0.41499456 -0.7074952  1.9803999
# [7,] -0.39428995  0.3645820 -0.3672215
# [8,] -0.05931340  0.7685329 -1.0441346
# [9,]  1.10002537 -0.1123462  0.5697196
#[10,]  0.76317575  0.8811077 -0.1350546

#[[3]]
#             [,1]         [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  2.40161776  0.475509529 -0.5686687
# [2,] -0.03924000 -0.709946431 -0.1351786
# [3,]  0.68973936  0.610726353  1.1780870
# [4,]  0.02800216 -0.934097632 -1.5235668
# [5,] -0.74327321 -1.253633400  0.5939462
# [6,]  0.18879230  0.291446236  0.3329504
# [7,] -1.80495863 -0.443291873  1.0630998
# [8,]  1.46555486  0.001105352 -0.3041839
# [9,]  0.15325334  0.074341324  0.3700188
#[10,]  2.17261167 -0.589520946  0.2670988
```

---

Or with `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(indexlist, ~ test1[, .x])
```